# Using Tcp Sockets on real Android devices

Tags: android, sockets, system-calls, ports

Can i use Tcp Sockets to connect two Android Devices(not Emulators) giving the proper IP adress taken by a WIFI network? Should i do port forwarding through a specific port? Is it possible to open a port programmatically using system calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can i use Tcp Sockets to connect two Android Devices(not Emulators) giving the proper IP adress taken by a WIFI network?**
Read up on this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html

**Should i do port forwarding through a specific port?**
From taking a quick peak at that site it seems to you have to do it, however i suggest that you read the link and see for yourself.

**Is it possible to open a port programmatically using system calls?**
Not anyway that i know if, have to log into your router and open it.

Comment: I mean in my android device(last question);

Comment: I don't think you need to open any ports on your device (not in any of my apps at least), sockets handle that i guess.

Comment: I am dealing with some problems in an app that i am developping. You thimk you colud give me a hint. Plz look my other questions through my profile if you have time to spare. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Q: Yes, absolutely

Here's a good link (one of many, including the Android documentation):

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

Basically, "sockets are sockets".  No problem.